# Multiple service http calls using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller I am calling a service with the following code:

```
Service.updateData(data).then(function (result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

In my service I am using $q to get multiple HTTP requests.

```
$rootScope.http_1 = $http.get();
$rootScope.http_2 = $http.get();

$q.all([$rootScope.http_1, $rootScope.http_2]).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result[0], result[1]);
    return result[0], result[1];
});
```

The code actually works as the http requests are successfully made. However, I get an error in the controller which says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. I believe this is due the service not returning the promise in the correct way. Any ideas on how to resolve this would be much appreciated?

Comment: What does `updateData` return? Also I don't see how you'll use the results of `then` callback function, hence I really can't find any use for `return` there (and it's written wrongly in any case). Finally, why do you decorate `$rootScope` with them, and not use local variables instead?

Comment: It doesn't return anything as I get a JS error. But the HTTP calls do work because I can see the result[0] & result[1] in console from the service. Any idea on how I could adapt the code in the controller to get a return of result[0] result[1] back to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not returning the promise in `updateData` Try this:

```
updateData = function(data) {
    $rootScope.http_1 = $http.get();
    $rootScope.http_2 = $http.get();

    return $q.all([$rootScope.http_1, $rootScope.http_2]);
}
```

1. You didn't return the promise, so there is nothing to call `.then()` on in your controller
2. You are returning inside the `.then()` function inside your `service.updateData()`, which doesn't do very much for you.

If you want to control it all inside the service and return a specific format, try this:

```
updateData = function(data) {
    $rootScope.http_1 = $http.get();
    $rootScope.http_2 = $http.get();
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $q.all([$rootScope.http_1, $rootScope.http_2]).then(function(result){
       // process here to get the data how you want it, say in some new var foo
       var foo = "some processed data based on result";
       defer.resolve(foo);
    });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks deitch. I would like to keep it within a service. However, when I use your 2nd bit code along with my code for the controller I get a new error: TypeError: undefined is not a function (and this points to the then on the controller).

Comment: Adding .promise to the defer got it working. Thanks again

`return defer.promise;`

Comment: Oh, yeah, sloppy of me! And I use `return defer.promise` all of the time. Sorry. :-)